# Java Portable Tomcat creating directories on desktop

Tags: java, tomcat

I've recently had to take over a project from an old co-worker; this project is written in JAVA, uses Java Web-Start and uses a light Java library (*org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat*).

Whenever the Tomcat server starts-up and I first interact with the web apps, it creates 3 directories (store, sys, temp) on the Windows desktop.

When I look at a normal Tomcat installation, those directories exist in the **tomcatHome\bin\** directory.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to redirect the creation of these directories to my **C:\TomcatHome\** directory?

**Below is a snippet of my code:**

```
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader;

...

// Define the user.dir directory.
System.setProperty( "user.dir", "C:\\TomcatHome" );
// Print out the user.dir and user.home system variables.
System.out.println( "user.dir = " + System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) );
System.out.println( "user.home = " + System.getProperty( "user.home" ) );

...

Tomcat m_tomcat = new Tomcat();
m_tomcat.setBaseDir( "C:\\TomcatHome" );
m_tomcat.setPort( 5009 );
m_tomcat.getHost().setDeployOnStartup( true );
m_tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy( true );
m_tomcat.getHost().setAppBase( "C:\\TomcatHome\\webapps" );
m_tomcat.getServer().setPort( 5109 );
m_tomcat.getServer().setShutdown( "SHUTDOWN" );

...

// Add abc web-application to Tomcat.
Context ctx = m_tomcat.addWebapp( null, "/abc", "abc" );
ctx.setLoader( new WebappLoader( class.getClassLoader() ) );
// Add xyz web-application to Tomcat.
ctx = m_tomcat.addWebapp(null, "/xyz", xyz );
ctx.setLoader( new WebappLoader( class.getClassLoader() ) );
// Add ROOT folder to Tomcat.
ctx = m_tomcat.addWebapp(null, "", "ROOT" );
ctx.setLoader( new WebappLoader( class.getClassLoader() ) );

...

m_tomcat.start();
```

**This code prints-out:**

```
user.dir = C:\TomcatHome
user.home = C:\Users\myName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are temporary directories. As seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads) check `catalina.sh` for the temp folder configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply... but my application is using a portable/lite, whatever you want to call it, version of Tomcat.  There is no catalina.sh file that I can see :(

Comment: I should add that I tried setting the CATALINA_TMPDIR system variable prior to running the Tomcat instance, and it didn't change the location of the temp files.

Comment: I also tried setting the catalina.home and catalina.base system variables as the Tomcat.setBaseDir(...) methods JavaDoc states.  But this didn't change the location either. I feel like this may be a bug in the org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... turns out that the names of the directories was causing confusion. The application that i have to support creates directories with these names in the user.dir location :(  Since these directories are created, but not documented, I had no idea that it was our code.